# Create new attributes inside a PHP object, through external values

Tags: php, class, object, attributes

In my case I'm creating a module for Drupal passing datasets from a database to another. I want to use the default function **node_save()**, so I need to create a node object with a **stdClass()**.
Once I've exported the dataset into an array like in this example:

```
 $values = array(
     "data1" => "example1",
     "data2" => "example2",
     ...
 );
```

I need to put the values in this way

```
$node = stdClass();
$node->title = 'Example';
```

Running through the array it could be easier create an attribute like title and pass it the interested value like:

```
foreach ($values as $key) {
   $node->$key = $values[$key];
}
```

There's a way to create the attribute automatically like

```
$node->$key
```

And pass it a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one (instead of `$node->$key` try to use `$node->{$key}`):

```
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
   $node->{$key} = $val;
}
```

For your example array:

```
$values = array(
     "data1" => "example1",
     "data2" => "example2",
     ...
 );
```

The code above will output:

```
$node->data1 = "example1";
$node->data2 = "example2";

object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["data1"]=> string(8) "example1"
  ["data2"]=> string(8) "example2"
}
```

Comment: Solved! Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If your array is single dimensional than you can simply type hint that array as an object like as

```
$values = array(
     "data1" => "example1",
     "data2" => "example2",
);

$values = (object) $values;

echo $values->data1;//example1
```